# How to calculate Future Value (FV) using sas sql

Tags: sql, sas

I need to calculate the FV value for the following formula in  Sas sql.
FV(Rate/100,-nper,pmt)

Comment: So what's the issue? FV is a valid SAS function. Are you having issues with the output? Please post more details including anything you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you've given; [RTFM](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/a003180371.htm#a003185266)

[Example:](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003180371.htm#a003206552)

```
data _null_;
   rate = 0.06/12;
   nper = 10;
   pmt = -200;
   pv = -500;
   type = 1;
   r = finance('fv', rate, nper, pmt, pv, type);
   put r = ;
run;
The value of r that is returned is 2581.4033741.
```

SAS SQL?

```
PROC SQL;
   ...
QUIT;
```